# What units is the most effective in auto-resolve for its upkeep?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I want to construct an army (and fleet) that will be the most effective in auto-resolves for its upkeep (ie. there is no army that can be constructed that can outperform it while not having higher upkeep). I'm playing as Rome.

How can I do this? Are there any rules that the auto-resolver follows? What is the optimal composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building an army with a single unit type. The Auto-Resolve stances increase different unit type. For example, **you can build an army of Velites, which are cheap, and use the Protective stance**, *that increases missile units's strength, and reducere melee units's effectiviness*.
In fact, stances give the following advantages/disadvantages:

- The Agressive stance increases the effectiviness of melee units, reduces the power of missile units, and is likely to give in more casualties. For sieges, it also privirea a bonus for sieges engines.
- The Balanced stance is perfect for balanced armies, since it doesn't privire any unit type-specific advantage/disadvantage, and the casualties are moderate.
- The Protective stance gives an advantage to missile units, but it reduces the effectiviness of melee units. Casualties are usually lower.

The same thing applies for ships. Bear in mind that Support Ships are the missile units, and Assault Ships are melee units.

Comment: What about cheap units vs. expensive units? I've heard that numbers are most important, which suggests lots of cheap troops would work better than equivalent (in upkeep) force of elite troops

Comment: I think yes, since in Total War Rome II the difference of power between average and elite units is much more insignificant than in previous titles. Use a large army of cheap unite than a small army of elite unite. This is the most cost-effective strategy. I could add that in Rome Total War (the older one) bringing an Urban Cohort could result in an Heroic Victory while auto-resolving, something that doesn't happen în Total War Rome II. @Superbest